# How to derive a sign-in key for AWS Signature Version 4 (in ColdFusion)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, coldfusion, amazon-kms

I am trying to use ColdFusion to access Amazon Web Services (AWS) using their current authentication method known as Signature Version 4.  I have consulted their documentation which has code examples for [several programming languages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html), as well as pseudo-code for [other languages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-other).  They provided some test input values to pass in to my script's signature function, and also some expected results.

Here are the test inputs:

```
key = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
dateStamp = '20120215'
regionName = 'us-east-1'
serviceName = 'iam'
```

Here are the expected results:

```
kSecret  = '41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559'
kDate    = '969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d'
kRegion  = '69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c'
kService = 'f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa'
kSigning = 'f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d'
```

The correct value for "kSigning" should be this:

```
f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d
```

However, for "kSigning" my code generates this:

```
31A84DCE0538A8B15ED68CCFBD803F17947E41BF625EFFD1AD6A67FC821F9BE2
```

I am using Railo 4.2.  Can someone please help me solve this, so that the anticipated value matches the dumped value?  Here's my ColdFusion markup:

```
<cfsilent>

<!--- HMACSHA256 --->
<cffunction name="sign" returntype="binary" access="private" output="false" hint="Sign with NSA SHA-256 Algorithm">
   <cfargument name="signMessage" type="string" required="true" />
   <cfargument name="signKey" type="string" required="true" />

   <cfset var jMsg = JavaCast("string",arguments.signMessage).getBytes("utf-8") />
   <cfset var jKey = JavaCast("string",arguments.signKey).getBytes("utf-8") />
   <cfset var key = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec") />
   <cfset var mac = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac") />

   <cfset key = key.init(jKey,"HmacSHA256") />
   <cfset mac = mac.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm()) />
   <cfset mac.init(key) />

   <cfreturn mac.doFinal(jMsg) />
</cffunction>

<!--- Get Signature Key --->
<cffunction name="getSignatureKey" returntype="binary" access="private" output="false" hint="Derive the sign-in key">
    <cfargument name="key" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="dateStamp" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="regionName" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="serviceName" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfset var kSecret = "AWS4" & arguments.key />
    <cfset var kDate = sign( arguments.dateStamp, kSecret ) />
    <cfset var kRegion = sign( arguments.regionName, kDate ) />
    <cfset var kService = sign( arguments.serviceName, kRegion ) />
    <cfset var kSigning = sign( arguments.serviceName, kService ) />

    <cfreturn kSigning />
</cffunction>

</cfsilent><!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AWS Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<cfset kSecret = getSignatureKey( 
    'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY', 
    '20120215', 
    'us-east-1', 
    'iam' 
) />
<cfdump var="#BinaryEncode(kSecret, 'hex')#" label="kSecret" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've been meaning to upgrade my script from 2 to 4 as well. But in the mean time this might give you some headway. https://gist.github.com/CFJSGeek/3f6f14ba86049af75361

Comment: When you get it figured out I'd love to see your results!

Comment: I spent a good 72 hours straight trying to figure the signature  version 4 with aws webservice out, I finally got the token right as expected like the code samples and when I. Sent it to the was service, I still got an authentication error. Spent subsequent hours with aws corporate tiered support (we're a named account) and the engineer couldn't figure out why the service was declining the REST calls. Ended downloading the java sdk and using that instead. Love aws, hate their rest implementation. It's buggy as hell. Good luck!

Comment: @ChrisTierney - I know this was a while ago, but I put together a first version of a [Signature 4 Utility](https://gist.github.com/Leigh-/a2798584b79fd9072605a4cc7ff60df4). Still very much alpha quality, but seems to work so far with the [S3Wrapper.cfc](https://gist.github.com/Leigh-/26993ed79c956c9309a9dfe40f1fce29) (tested with CF11).

Comment: @Leigh - nice! thanks for the heads up - I'll have to check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `<cfset var kRegion = sign( arguments.regionName, kDate ) />`

I am little surprised the code runs without error, as the `sign()` function expects two strings, but the code is actually passing in a byte array for the second parameter. (Under CF11 it throws an error). Perhaps there is some sort of implicit conversion going on? 
Anyway, after refactoring the functions slightly, the example worked fine with one exception. The very last line of the example uses the literal string "aws4_request" rather than "arguments.serviceName". See example below.

Having said that, does not Railo have an HMAC function you can use rather than rolling your own? I am guessing so, as [HMAC()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html) is included in CF10+. **Update:** As [vrtjason noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513197/how-to-derive-a-sign-in-key-for-aws-signature-version-4-in-coldfusion#comment52917156_32514716), Railo added the `HMAC()` function in [4.0.0.011](https://github.com/getrailo/railo/commit/f36bd5c72c3dc084b08aab9edeabba43f5a7548b). However, for backward compatibility the java version below should work with most any version.

**Example:**

```
result = getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName);
writeDump( binaryEncode(result, "hex") );
```

**Results:**

```
F4780E2D9F65FA895F9C67B32CE1BAF0B0D8A43505A000A1A9E090D414DB404D
```

**Functions:**

```
<cffunction name="getSignatureKey" returntype="binary" access="private" output="false" hint="Derive the sign-in key">
    <cfargument name="key" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="dateStamp" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="regionName" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="serviceName" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfset Local.kSecret = charsetDecode("AWS4" & arguments.key, "UTF-8") />
    <cfset Local.kDate = sign( arguments.dateStamp, Local.kSecret ) />
    <cfset Local.kRegion = sign( arguments.regionName, Local.kDate ) />
    <cfset Local.kService = sign( arguments.serviceName, Local.kRegion ) />
    <cfset Local.kSigning = sign( "aws4_request", Local.kService ) />

    <cfreturn Local.kSigning />
</cffunction>




<cffunction name="sign" returntype="binary" access="private" output="false" hint="Sign with NSA SHA-256 Algorithm">
   <cfargument name="message" type="string" required="true" />
   <cfargument name="key" type="binary" required="true" />
   <cfargument name="algorithm" type="string" default="HmacSHA256" />
   <cfargument name="encoding" type="string" default="UTF-8" />

   <cfset Local.keySpec = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec") />
   <cfset Local.keySpec = Local.keySpec.init( arguments.key, arguments.algorithm ) />
   <cfset Local.mac = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac").getInstance( arguments.algorithm ) />
   <cfset Local.mac.init( Local.keySpec ) />

   <cfreturn Local.mac.doFinal( charsetDecode(arguments.message, arguments.encoding ) ) />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Thanks, Leigh!  I produced the same result on my end.  Outstanding work.

By the way, it appears that [hmac was added in Railo 4.0.0.011](https://github.com/getrailo/railo/commit/f36bd5c72c3dc084b08aab9edeabba43f5a7548b), so for backward compatibility I think it's helpful to have dipped into Java for the hmac.

Comment: Ah, thanks for posting the version info. I added it to the answer for greater visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem and expect you will see it, too, when you note how similar these two lines are:

```
<cfset var kService = sign( arguments.serviceName, kRegion ) />
<cfset var kSigning = sign( arguments.serviceName, kService ) />
```

Red flag alert, does it make sense to hmac the service name twice?

The input to the last step is a string literal.

```
<cfset var kSigning = sign( "aws4_request", kService ) />
```

Comment: Darn it! Spent too long typing up an answer ;-)

Comment: lol @Leigh I hate it when that happens.  At least we came up with the same answer for the specific error, but +1 to you for the detailed analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this in ColdFusion 10+ using the built in HMAC() function without needing to Create a Java Object:

```
function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
    var kDate= lCase(HMAC(ARGUMENTS.dateStamp,"AWS4" & ARGUMENTS.key,"hmacsha256"));
    var kRegion= lCase(HMAC(ARGUMENTS.regionName,binaryDecode(kDate,'hex'),"hmacsha256"));
    var kService=lCase(HMAC(ARGUMENTS.serviceName,binaryDecode(kRegion,'hex'),"hmacsha256"));
    var kSigning= lCase(HMAC("aws4_request",binaryDecode(kService,'hex'),"hmacsha256"));

    return kSigning;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely.  The asker chose to keep the java version (for backward compatibility), but for new code using the built in HMAC function is the way to go.