# Get an AWS SignatureDoesNotMatch error when trying to build a request in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, aws-sdk

Here is the code I am using:

```
<cfsilent>

<cffunction name="getSignatureKey" returntype="binary" access="private" output="false" hint="Derive the sign-in key">
   <cfargument name="key" type="string" required="true" />
   <cfargument name="dateStamp" type="string" required="true" />
   <cfargument name="regionName" type="string" required="true" />
   <cfargument name="serviceName" type="string" required="true" />

   <cfset Local.kSecret = charsetDecode("AWS4" & arguments.key, "UTF-8") />
   <cfset Local.kDate = sign( arguments.dateStamp, Local.kSecret ) />
   <cfset Local.kRegion = sign( arguments.regionName, Local.kDate ) />
   <cfset Local.kService = sign( arguments.serviceName, Local.kRegion ) />
   <cfset Local.kSigning = sign( "aws4_request", Local.kService ) />
   <cfreturn Local.kSigning />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="sign" returntype="binary" access="private" output="false" hint="Sign with NSA SHA-256 Algorithm">
   <cfargument name="message" type="string" required="true" />
   <cfargument name="key" type="binary" required="true" />
   <cfargument name="algorithm" type="string" default="HmacSHA256" />
   <cfargument name="encoding" type="string" default="UTF-8" />

   <cfset Local.keySpec = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec") />
   <cfset Local.keySpec = Local.keySpec.init( arguments.key, arguments.algorithm ) />
   <cfset Local.mac = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac").getInstance( arguments.algorithm ) />
   <cfset Local.mac.init( Local.keySpec ) />
   <cfreturn Local.mac.doFinal( charsetDecode(arguments.message, arguments.encoding ) ) />
</cffunction>

</cfsilent>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>AWS Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <cfset kSecret = getSignatureKey( 
                        'mysecretaccesskey', 
                        '20160408', 
                        'us-west-1', 
                        'AWSECommerceService' 
                    ) />

    <cfset MyDateTime = now()>
    <cfset urlstring="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=myaccesskeyID&Timestamp=#DateFormat(MyDateTime,"YYYY-MM-DD")#T#TimeFormat(DateAdd('h', 5 , MyDateTime),'HH:MM:SS')#Z&Signature=#BinaryEncode(kSecret, 'hex')#&BrowseNodeId=2625373011&Operation=BrowseNodeLookup&ResponseGroup=TopSellers&Service=AWSECommerceService">

   <cfdump var="#urlstring#">

   <CFHTTP URL="#urlstring#" result="data">
   <cfdump var="#data#">

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error from Amazon AWS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<BrowseNodeLookupErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05">
   <Error>
      <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
      <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>28a54988-fda5-11e5-87c7-d5c13ae487c7</RequestId>
</BrowseNodeLookupErrorResponse>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'll ask my AWS guys for you - but you might check out http://www.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.search#aws - perhaps a clue would be found by examining what other devs have done with AWS eh?

Comment: One comment from one of my gurus - he’s calling charsetDecode() with a encoding type of AWS - I’m not seeing that as a valid type. Maybe that helps.  .... but that may not be your issue.

Comment: You might have better luck using HMac in ColdFusion instead of using the java crypto. I have an example for S3 and it uses an older signature version, but you should be able to just pull the good parts. Your getSignatureKey method looks correct (referencing http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-java), but I've never tested something like that. See methods HMAC_SHA1() and createSignature() : https://gist.github.com/CFJSGeek/3f6f14ba86049af75361

Comment: I am not 100% sure I should be passing mysecretaccesskey in the GetSignatureKey function VS myaccesskeyid

Comment: I used most of the code from this stackoverflow QA - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513197/how-to-derive-a-sign-in-key-for-aws-signature-version-4-in-coldfusion

Comment: See the section "Deriving the Signing Key with Other Languages" in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-java to match against what it expects.

Comment: @user1322114 - That link is just about deriving the signing key. Looking at their documentation, that is only one part of [generating the signature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html).

Comment: Those documents just state 'key', is that the 'secretaccesskey' or 'accesskeyid' or a combination of both?

Comment: (Edit) If you look at "Task 3", it says "Your AWS Secret Access Key", but again the code from the other thread (which validates against the example on Amazon) is only for generating the signing key. So I do not believe this will work: `Signature=#BinaryEncode( kSecret , 'hex')#`, because `kSecret` is just the *key* used for signing the request. It does not contain the actual signature itself.

Comment: So you think I got the right keys in the right places, you just don't agree how the signature is being built.  Do you have any idea of how to correct my code to get the correct signature?

Comment: You have to do [all four (4) steps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html) to construct the signature. Essentially, 1) Arrange the contents of [the] request (headers, etcetera). 2) Create the "string to sign" 3) Generate the signing key and signature and 4) Add it to the cfhttp request. The project Chris linked above has the basic idea.

Comment: One thing you forgot to mention was which API are you trying to use. The url looks like Product Advertising API, but the docs say for REST it [".. supports only Signature Version 2."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Query_QueryAuth.html). If that is the case, have you tried an existing tool like http://amazonsig.riaforge.org/ ? Not sure how current it is, but they also have a testing tool https://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html

Comment: Leigh is right about using http://amazonsig.riaforge.org/. That has worked for me in the past. If you want to stick with your own code, one simple thing to check is if your output is coming out all upper or lower case. The signature casing matters and ColdFusion may be converting case at some point in the process.

Comment: Yes, if the API uses the old style signature v2, that is the right direction. I thought (probably incorrectly) you required signature 4.